# How to print whole json data

Tags: node.js

Why for loop is not working , but on individual data it works.
I'm trying to fetch 3 inputs from the api, book name , author name and subject.

```
     <table class="table table-bordered">
    <h1 align="center">List of Science Book Records</h1>
    &nbsp;
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Book Name</th>
        <th>Author Name</th>
        <th>Publish Date</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="mypanel">


<script>
    $.getJSON('https://openlibrary.org/subjects/science.json', function(data) {
     for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
         console.log("hii");
         var text = `<tr><td>${data.works[i].title}</td>
                    <td>${data.works[i].authors[i].name}</td>
                <td>${data.name}</td></tr>`


         $(".mypanel").html(text);
     }
    });
</script>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi. In order to help you we need to know scheme of this JSON. Can you provide and example of if?

Comment: try using `.append(text)` instead of `.html(text)`

Comment: JSON FILE : https://openlibrary.org/subjects/science.json

Comment: Used append but  its not working

Comment: change your for loop to: for (var i=0;i<data.works.length;i++)

Comment: If I  want data of subject, how can i get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should looping data.works instead. Check the following snippet.
I'm assuming that data.works[i].autors has only one position, if not, you can loop them as well.
Finally prepend to the div with class myPanel.
Hope it helps.

```js
$.getJSON('https://openlibrary.org/subjects/science.json', function(data) {
     for (var i=0;i<data.works.length;i++) {
         
         var text = `<tr><td>${data.works[i].title}</td>
                    <td>${data.works[i].authors[0].name}</td>
                <td>${data.name}</td></tr>`


         $(".mypanel").append(text);
     }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <h1 align="center">List of Science Book Records</h1>
    &nbsp;
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Book Name</th>
        <th>Author Name</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="mypanel">
```

Comment: But sir , i want author name with his book name , how can i retrieve this data ..

Comment: author.name and work[i].title (name) is what you want , right?

Comment: On the example it is working. What you trying to achieve?

Comment: See the json file file which i shared , i want book name with author name

Answer (score 0):

Judging from JSON structure that you have, you're iterating over the `length` of an object `data` which is `undefined`.

In order to show the list of `works` you need to iterate over the `length` of `works` so your loop will look like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.works.length; i++) {
    // do stuff with data.works[i]
}
```

And also you can use append in each iteration of the loop OR you can summarize all text, and then append it after the loop, by doing

```
text += `<tr><td>${data.works[i].title}</td>
    <td>${data.works[i].authors[i].name}</td>
    <td>${data.name}</td></tr>`;
```

But don't forget to define variable `text` before the loop.